# getCallingUid/getCallingPid return current uid and pid in Handler.handleMessage

Tags: android

I have a class extending `android.os.Handler`. An instance of this handler is passed to the constructor of a `Messenger`. The `Messenger`'s `IBinder` from `getBinder` is passed as the result of `onBind` events in my service. Messages sent via the binder from remote applications do go to the handler's `handleMessage` method, however calls to `Binder.getCallingUid` and `Binder.getCallingPid` within `handleMessage` always return the uid and pid of the service's process (which is definitely not the same process as the remote application). `handleMessage` is definitely part of an IPC transaction, isn't it? So where have I gone wrong? I need this to work for authentication of connecting applications.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

OK. I have this horrible feeling that `handleMessage` is not part of the IPC transaction, because that happens in separate threads for AIDL which puts messages in a queue for the `Messenger`. Is there any other way of getting the User ID and Process ID of the caller?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make a custom `Handler` class and override `sendMessageAtTime` (this is the only overridable posting method in the `Handler` class ), and then use it to create a `Messenger` returned from `onBind`.

In the `sendMessageAtTime` method, you can get the pid/uid of the calling remote application by `getCallingPid` and `getCallingUid`.

But, in IPC using `Messenger`, as opposed to using AIDL, `getCallingPid` will always return 0 because the message sending by remote apps is asynchronous; transactions with `IBinder.FLAG_ONEWAY`.
Therefore the uid is the only information available.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Indeed, it looks like sendMessageAtTime gives the correct response on getCallingPid

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with what I feel is quite a neat way to fix this. All messages that come through IPC get reconstructed from a parcel using `Message.CREATOR.createFromParcel`. So I have created a Java Dynamic Proxy Class (code pulled straight from the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html)) that detects calls to `createFromParcel` and adds the process id and user id as additional items in the message's bundle before returning the result. The message is guaranteed to be created within a transaction, looking at the source for `Messenger`, so the IDs are correct. I then use reflection to replace the static final variable `Message.CREATOR` with a proxy of itself. IDs are then pulled out of messages later outside of transactions when authentication is required.

So far this is working exactly as intended.

Previously I was trying to create an alternative version of `Messenger`, and using reflection to access `IMessenger`, but even `Messenger` does not handle `Message`s before transactions end. A proxy is a lot less work and less prone to errors involved in casting different implementations of `IMessenger`.

Comment: This doesn't work in current Android.  Just as in sendMessageAtTime, you get the UID but not the PID.  This really isn't a good idea anyway, since it depends on undocumented system internals that can (and apparently did) change at any time.

Answer (score 0):

The code handling the message isn't involved in any IPC, you should instead be looking at the code which is posting the message to the handler.

Comment: Isn't that part of android itself? I am looking into wrapping a proxy around the `Messenger`'s `IBinder`. I'll see if I can add the pid and uid as extras for the message's bundle from within `transact`, possibly.

Comment: Doesn't look like implementing a simple wrapper around an `IBinder` is possible. Is there any way that I can wrap an `IBinder` in a subclass of `Binder`, then?

Comment: Ok. I think I can create a class using the same AIDL that behaves very similarly to Messenger, but adds in the pid and uid to each message received. I'll post back with results.